# ConnectionAbortedError [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: python, rest, request

I'm creating a python script with request. When I try to connect to the API, I'm using

```
response = session.get('https://localhost/api/client', verify=False)

print(response)
```

When I run the script, I end with
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. Can someone please explain me this error???

Comment: What web server is running on localhost?  Have you looked at the error log and access log?

Comment: @JohnGordon Its a NodeJS backend running behind an NGINX reverse proxy, each in their own docker containers. Neither of them are outputting any logs but when I send the request directly to the backend, the response goes through. Thats why I think it might be an issue with the way I'm configuring my headers. Postman, and then project's apps are able to send requests but the script I'm creating cannot.